# Paso de variables a un Cuadro de Diálogo Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Buenas tardes, ¿es posible pasar variables a un cuadro de diálogo en Android?

He creado una clase para el cuadro de diálogo y que obtenga la información desde el XML. Si quisiera que la obtuviese desde donde se instancia el objeto de la clase y que en el cuadro se muestre el valor de una variable, ¿Sería posible?

```
public class Informacion extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {    
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, null))
                .setTitle("Información")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
 return builder.create();
    }
}
```

y se ejecuta con el botón:

```
Button buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.informacion);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Informacion dialogo = new Informacion();
            dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagAlerta");
        }
    });
```

Gracias!!!

Comment: Podrías crear un método con parámetros en tu respuesta del primer diálogo asignar los valores. sendOption(value1, value2); Éste método iniciaría tu diálogo con los valores q hayan sido envíados.

Answer (score 1):

Algo así te puede servir:

```
public class Informacion extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
private String message = "message";

public Informacion setMessage(String customMessage) {
    message = customMessage;
    return this;
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, null))
            .setTitle(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); return builder.create();}}
```

y lo puedes aplicar de la siguiente manera:

```
Button buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.informacion);
buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Informacion dialogo = new Informacion().setMessage("My custom message");
        dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagAlerta");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible, de hecho puedes ver un  ejemplo en la [**documentación**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), en el cual se crea un método `newInstance()` que sirve para incializar el `DialogFragment`, en donde se agregan valores en un `Bundle` que se agregan al `DialogFragment`:

```
 static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
```

---

En tu caso puedes agregar el método `newInstance()` a tu `DialogFragment`:

```
public static Informacion newInstance(String titulo, int valor) {
        Informacion frag = new Informacion();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("titulo", titulo);
        args.putInt("valor", valor);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
```

e inicializar los valores al llamar `newInstance()` para que tenga los valores:

```
Button buttonInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.informacion);
    buttonInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //Informacion dialogo = new Informacion();
            DialogFragment dialogo = Informacion.newInstance("Dialogo Maria", 12);
            dialogo.show(fragmentManager, "tagAlerta");
        }
    });
```

de esta forma en el método `onCreateDialog()` de tu `DialogFragment` puedes obtener los valores de esta forma:

```
public class Informacion extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {    
       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String myTitulo = getArguments().getInt("titulo");
        int myvalor = getArguments().getInt("valor");
        ...
        ...
       }
```